# How to control Meteor Session update and database subscription latency?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to limit the client side cache by changing the Collection (GraphData) subscription through Meteor.autorun. But I noticed that the server side only publish the data after the Session (browser GUI) is changed. Is that correct?

On the clients side I have the following coffeescript code:

```
Meteor.startup ->  
  Meteor.autorun () ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'graphdata', Session.get 'graph_name'
```

In a function, draw_graph, I have

```
Session.set 'graph_sub', false    
Session.set 'graph_name', item_name
ready = Session.get 'graph_sub'
while !(ready)    
  Meteor.setTimeout (ready = Session.get 'graph_sub'), 1000
Do something with the GraphData subscription
```

On the server side I have

```
Meteor.startup ->  
  Meteor.publish 'graphdata', (name) -> 
    if name?
      GraphData.find({name: name})
      Session.set 'graph_sub', true
```

I was expecting the server side publish to be triggered after Session.set 'graph_name', item_name but I noticed that I got stuck in the while loop.

Is my understanding correct? Anyway to force the Session variable changes get noticed on the server side without the Session change?

Comment: A loop `ready = false; setTimeout((-> ready = true), 1000) until ready` will not work as you want, it causes the inner `(-> ready = true)` to be called a bazillion times. (EDIT: Wrote it as a one-liner to fit this one-line comment format; compile to JS to see the issue more clearly.)

Comment: It very obviously won't work in the one-liner you provided since ready won't never change. In my code I was expecting ready to change to true once the serveire side set graph_sub to true. My original question was about the server side failed to set graph_sub to true.

Comment: Yes, this is probably a bit OT, but I do think that `ready` should eventually change after one second (and then a billion times again if it gets that far), it's just until then `setTimeout` has been called via the `while` loop a frightening number of times.

Answer (score 0):

```
while !(Session.get 'graph_sub')    
  Meteor.setTimeout (Session.get 'graph_sub'), 1000
```

Shouldn't the second line be `Session.set`? Otherwise the session value will never change, and the while loop will never end.

Besides the typo I'm confused why you're using a `setTimeout` and `graph_sub` in the first place. Wouldn't this be enough?

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.startup ->
    Meteor.autorun ->
      Meteor.subscribe 'graphdata', Session.get 'graph_name'

if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.startup ->
    Meteor.publish 'graphdata', (name) ->
      GraphData.find name: name
```

Comment: Yes, sorry for the type. I used graph_sub as a way to check the success of the subscription because the Collection could be quite big and take sometime to subscribe. I initially had exactly what you have but without the latency my process ended buy starting before the subscription was complete

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `Do something with the GraphData subscription` in the callback of `Meteor.subscribe`.

```
Meteor.startup ->  
  Meteor.autorun () ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'graphdata', Session.get 'graph_name', () ->
      Do something with the GraphData subscription
```

Also note that session is not available on server side anymore since 0.5.8: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md#v058.

Comment: There are three sets of data in the GraphData collection: applications, appliances, and gateways which are passed in as the graph_name. The Do something with the GraphData subscription is different from each different data set. I cannot move it to be under Meteor.subscribe.